How to splice to Romex in a code-compliant way
This question is specifically in regards to LED transformers / drivers with either:

120vac pigtails (example), or
120vac terminals protected by an enclosure (example)

My understanding is that these transformers can be UL listed and can be installed in a code-compliant way (example). But how is the interface with the romex actually done?
I believe the transformer needs to be mounted outside of the wall.
The video and the images on the 2nd amazon listing suggest that you can just run the cable out of the junction box and underneath the switch faceplate directly to the transformer. That seems super-hacky. Maybe you could drill a hole in the faceplate (including a jbox that's used for the splice with a blank faceplate) and run the cable out? Probably use a rubber grommet.
This assumes that this is done in a place the cables are protected, but if we're talking about, e.g., the inside of a kitchen cabinet, then I guess you'd need conduit?
In the second example (enclosure) you could use conduit coming out of the wall (some sort of right-angle connector to a box, presumably?) that connects to the hole on the enclosure.
Edit: TBH, I wasn't happy with the answers so I searched for [electrician installs cabinet led driver] on youtube. I only found enclosure-style lighting and, except for one electrician who bought a plug, cut it off then hardwired that to the terminals, the common solution seemed to be to just pull the romex out of a hole in the wall and/or cabinet without any sort of grommet (e.g. 1, 2, 3). I couldn't find any examples of pig-tail drivers. But, to answer my original question, based on these "internet electricians", then it'd be OK to push the romex out of knock-out in the in-wall switch junction box, over a few inches to a hole drilled in the wall, then out of the hole into a knock-out in the enclosure. This feels hacky and the reason I was looking for suggestions, but it seems commonly done. (Even in the old days before separate drivers and strips).

Can you provide any information on your use case?

To ask and answer the obvious unstated question, "why do they sell sh*t like this" the answer is, it's designed for product manufacturers and professional installers who will be creating their own enclosures or doing other creative things.    Then it's listed on Amazon where the low price attracts consumers who want to use it as-is.  And in fact you can be a little creative.  EG put several of these in a project box with a terminal strip to power them and a plug from the project box to an outlet.  But you can't just pretend it's something it isn't.

My use case is installing an LED driver inside of a kitchen cabinet for under-cabinet light strips. Many of the LED drivers I'm finding have terminals or pigtails. In fact, I'd like to "wall-mount" the driver (screw it to the wall), and most of these have pigtails or terminals. (E.g., https://www.btf-lighting.com/collections/24v-power-supply -- BTF is a main supplier of strips).  So my assumption was that if so many of these are offered (including UL-listed ones) then they must be easily installable in a compliant way. Guess not.

Regarding the last paragraph you just added, and the three videos.  If you come out of an existing box (eg switch box) with Romex using a correct NM cable strain relief, run behind the wall, then through the wall directly into a knockout, mounted flush against said wall, of an enclosure designed for that purpose, also with an NM strain relief clamp that's not sketchy at all, it's exactly how it's meant to be done.  NM running inside walls, never exposed, between metal boxes correctly terminated at both ends.   The metal boxes can be mounted in the wall or surface mounted.  Both ok.

Item 1 is not UL listed.
Items 2 and 3 give standard knockouts.
Standard knockouts are the universal donor, because any conduit wiring system can dock up to them, as well as Romex with these clamps, FMC with these clamps, etc.

The video and the images on the 2nd amazon listing suggest that you can just run the wire out of the junction box and underneath the switch faceplate directly to the transformer

A "cable" is several "wires" wrapped in a sheath.
They don't suggest that to me, but I have more experience.  You run the cable from the switch in the normal way, in the walls, like any other cable.  If that's new to you, get a book on home electrical or bring in a pro.
They seem to be saying you come into the KO with normal wiring methods. If you're going to surface mount that gadget inside a cabinet, coming out a knockout with Romex and plunging into the wall would be sketch. FMC would be better. A conduit pull elbow or LB conduit body  would be pro tier, to provide physical protection to the Romex. Once it's inside the wall, the conduit can just end and the Romex exit and run in the wall.

Edit: Replace #1 with this, for example: https://www.glowbackledstore.com/12v-72watt-ul-listed-led-driver-for-led-strips-12v6alp13/ or https://hitlights.com/products/96-watt-mini-dimmable-driver-24-volt
Regarding #2, my question was what's the interface between the wall and the device. I get that you have a KO in the device in #2, but how does the cable get from inside the wall to outside the wall? E.g., an in-wall JB with a surface-mount JB with a romex clamp to bare romex for a few inches to the romex clamp in the KO in #2?

Discussed in last sentence @JamesS.  Let me add links.

So that's what I'm getting at -- the interface between in-wall romex and the transformer. Going with your FMC / elbow / LB suggestion, the question remains on how to terminate it "inside the wall". AFAIK, there is no "conduit exit junction box", such as a JB inside the wall with a faceplate that has a 1/2" screw outlet (or, even better, a 1/2" male connector that your elbow / LB suggestion would screw onto). So if you have FMC / elbow / LB on the outside, would you simply drill a 1/2" hole in the wall, and shove the bitter-end in, then strap it up so it doesn't pop out?

The interface between in-wall Romex and an external device with a power cord is a plug.  Sorry.  There are exceptions: ceiling fixtures, large permanent appliances, door bells. Lots more. Those all have provision for connection through a knockout, and specific exception in code.  You could rig it up with a cable gland in a knockout but why?  A consumer device mounted externally with a power cord, next to a junction box .... why do anything other than a plug and socket?  It's also easier to diagnose when they inevitably fail.

@JamesS you can't terminate any cable inside the wall, they may only be terminated at boxes or equipment. So the Romex run from your power supply to the light switch etc. would be one piece of cable.   If you need splices, then mount a junction box and do it in there. But as jay613 says, at that point might as well put a receptacle inside the J-box provided you aren't dimming it. (can't dim NEMA receptacles).

Item 1 can't go in a wall.  If it was UL listed you could put a plug on it (er, if it was listed it would have a plug?).   You could screw it to the underside of a cabinet or place it on top, etc.   and plug it into an outlet.

Replaced the example in #1 with https://www.glowbackledstore.com/12v-72watt-ul-listed-led-driver-for-led-strips-12v6alp13/ . There's also https://hitlights.com/products/96-watt-mini-dimmable-driver-24-volt. See the fourth photo which is a picture of the wiring diagram. The wiring diagram suggests its hard-wired and definitely doesn't imply that you'd add a plug to it and then install an outlet.

Neither new example is designed for in-wall installation.  The first one even says "external JBOX".  You install a surface-mount metal box, or metal cover plate with a knockout.  Then use a knockout with a suitable strain relief bushing for the rubber power cord, such as for a ceiling lamp or an oven.  Why do that instead of a plug is beyond me.  The first new example also has "hardwired" in quotation marks which is amusing.   And even if you do this it's still not strictly kosher. Most of these PSUs have a plug on the cord. Buy one.

Yeah. I never said I wanted to put it in a wall, or that it should go in a wall. I stated "outside of the wall" just to make it clear I was excluding consideration of in-wall installation options. I disagree that "most .. have a plug". I just searched for "LED driver" on amazon and 12 of the first 14 had terminals or pigtails."UL listed led driver" is similar, though the terminals are enclosed. But, ultimately, I think you're right that -- despite the prevalence -- there are code-compliant and hacky ways (see my new findings on my question) but they're all kinda sketch.
